# How to create random values for each key created in a dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a list into a dictionary and assign the value from each key a random value, but I am seeming to have some trouble with it. Here is a sample of my code ...

```
def assign_players_value(player_list):
  choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
  player_dictionary = dict.fromkeys(player_list, (random.choice(choices) for p in range(number_of_players)))
  print (player_dictionary)
```

Do keep in mind, the player_list looks like ["P1", "P2", "P3"...]

My intended output is something like {"P1" : "Rock", "P2" : "Scissors" , "P3" : "Paper" ... }

But instead, I get {'P1': <generator object assign_players_value.. at 0x000001B88B0FD350>, 'P2': <generator object assign_players_value.. at 0x000001B88B0FD350>, ...

Comment: you have a few bugs. `dict.fromkeys` accept one value, here you pass a list. in addition, with this logic you can get the same value for multiple keys. i would suggest popping a random item from the list in a while loop instead

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```py
def assign_player_value(player_list):
  choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
  player_dictionary = {i: random.choice(choices) for i in player_list}
  print(player_dictionary)
```

This way you can get

```
In [4]: assign_player_value(["P1", "P2", "P3"])
{'P1': 'Scissors', 'P2': 'Rock', 'P3': 'Scissors'}
```

You are getting generator because of tuple comprehension `(random.choice(choices) for p in range(number_of_players))`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```py
>>> import random
>>> def assign_players_value(player_list):
...     choices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
...     return dict([(player, random.choice(choices)) for player in player_list])
... 
>>> assign_players_value(["P1", "P2", "P3"])
{'P1': 'Rock', 'P2': 'Rock', 'P3': 'Scissors'}
>>>
```